# Flash CC - Control Key

Tags: flash, copy, key, controls, flash-cc

I got installed a new version of Flash (CC) and I got little confused - control key doesn't copy a shape. In all previous versions, when I got Ctrl pressed and moved shape with a mouse, I was getting a clone. It was really helpful. Do you know how can I get this back?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shortcut has changed in Flash CC. You can press Alt and drag the shape in order to clone it.